# Android user permission request for more than one permission using Delphi 11.3

Tags: android, delphi, user-permissions, delphi-11-alexandria

Building an Android app with Delphi 11.3, I'd like to ask more than one user permission, explaining to the user why he needs to give me this permissions. Using this code in a DataModule:

```pascal
procedure SetPermissions();
const
  Explanation : string = 'you have to...';
begin
  TDialogService.MessageDialog(Explanation, TMsgDlgType.mtInformation, [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK], TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK, 0,
    procedure(const AResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      PermissionsService.RequestPermissions(Permissions,
        procedure(const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>)
        begin
          if (Length(AGrantResults) > 0) and (AGrantResults[0] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) then
          begin
            // permission granted
          end
          else
          begin
            // permission not granted
          end;
        end
      );
    end
  );
end;
```

It seems clear to me, simple and correct, but the compiler still says:

```
[DCC Error] udmMain.pas(287): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'RequestPermissions' that can be called with these arguments
[DCC Error] udmMain.pas(289): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'MessageDialog' that can be called with these arguments
```

I can't understand why! Please help me.

Comment: Delphi 11.3 has changed the function header. In requestpermissions you have to use TClassicStringDynArray and TClassicPermissionStatusDynArray instead of TArray<string> and  TArray<TPermissionStatus>

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question before one year ago?

Comment: Yes you're right, that method worked but not well in a 11.3 but thank you for this suggestion perhaps i was in panic! I have corrected as you said and it works, also  i would like to show a message to user and i was not able to do this only if the permission are not granted.

Comment: You should ask for the permission without using the messagedialog and move the messagedialog into the "no permission granted" section